# Django: How to cascade an update through multiple models?

Tags: python, django, model

I'm writing a Django based application to keep track of objects (Objekt) and their maintenance tasks. Objekts can be linked to a location.

Location (0/1) --- (n) Objekt (1) --- (n) Task

Location, Objekt and Task all have a status field with the following values:

```
    RED = "red"
    YELLOW = "yellow"
    GREEN = "green"
    STATUS = [
        (RED, "Overdue tasks"),
        (YELLOW, "Pending tasks"),
        (GREEN, "All good"),
    ]
```

I want that the Location map marker changes its color based on the status of the related Objekts and ultimatelly Tasks.

I've tried to follow [django best practices](https://django-best-practices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/applications.html#models) and create a fat model.

```
from django.db import models
from locationapp.models import Location
from taskapp.models import Task
from rules.contrib.models import RulesModel

class Objekt(RulesModel):
    RED = "red"
    YELLOW = "yellow"
    GREEN = "green"
    STATUS = [
        (RED, "Overdue tasks"),
        (YELLOW, "Pending tasks"),
        (GREEN, "All good"),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=STATUS, default=GREEN)

    def set_status(self):
        if Task.objects.filter(objekt=self.id).filter(status=Task.RED).exists():
            self.status = Objekt.RED
        elif Task.objects.filter(objekt=self.id).filter(status=Task.YELLOW).exists():
            self.status = Objekt.YELLOW
        else:
            self.status = Objekt.GREEN
```

But somehow I'm not sure about my concept here... How can an update on Task trigger an update on the related Objekt. And how would the Objekt further trigger the update on the Location - if required at all?

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution is to use signals. I've implemented it as following, without celery for now:

```
# objektapp/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ObjektappConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'objektapp'

    def ready(self):
        import objektapp.signals
```

```
# objektapp/signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import transaction
from taskapp.models import Task
from objektapp.models import Objekt

@receiver(post_save, sender=Task)
def set_status(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # TODO: Use celery for async operation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: objekt_update_status(instance))

def objekt_update_status(task_instance):
    objekt = Objekt.objects.get(id=task_instance.objekt.id)

    new_objekt_status = Objekt.GREEN
    if Task.objects.filter(objekt=task_instance.objekt.id, status=Task.RED).exists():
        new_objekt_status = Objekt.RED
    elif Task.objects.filter(objekt=task_instance.objekt.id, status=Task.YELLOW).exists():
        new_objekt_status = Objekt.YELLOW

    if objekt.status != new_objekt_status:
        objekt.status = new_objekt_status
        objekt.save()
```

A similar setup I've done on the Location model, which also reacts on a post_save signal from the Objekt. I am not sure if it's the best place to store the objekt_update_status() function in the signals.py file, but trying to put it into the models.py ended up with circular import error.